# Can't delete a cell from table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view were i'm performing a deletion, and everything worked until I changed my code in the table view controller class to work with a class manager thats providing the app data ,called LocalDataManager.

I can swipe and see the red button for deletion but nothing happened when I click it.

I found with the debugger that the problem is in my numberOfRowsInSection method.

this is my table view:

```
#import "StackTableViewController.h"
#import "Target.h"
#import "StackTableViewCell.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface StackTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        localDataManager = [[LocalDataManager alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [localDataManager reloadData];

    //[self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

// just to ignor a warning
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return localDataManager.fetchedResultController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [localDataManager.fetchedResultController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}




- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Target *target = [localDataManager.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[localDataManager.stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];

    [localDataManager.stack saveContext];


    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StackTableViewCell";

    Target *target = [localDataManager.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = target.body;

    cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

And this is my LocalDataManager.m:

```
#import "LocalDataManager.h"

@implementation LocalDataManager
@synthesize stack,fetchedResultController;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        //init
        stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
        fetchedResultController = [self fetchedResultController];
        [self reloadData];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)reloadData{
    [fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
}
- (NSFetchRequest *)targetsFetchRequest {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Target"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return fetchRequest;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController {

    if (fetchedResultController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultController;
    }



    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self targetsFetchRequest];

    fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:stack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    return fetchedResultController;

}


@end
```

The problem might be also with the last 3 methods of the table view, or the fact that i'm holding my FetchResultController from my manager class and not from the table view, but I don't know to point it directly..please help me to figure this out.

Thanks aallot!

Answer (score 1):

You never tell the table to remove the row after deleting the record from core data.

You need:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Target *target = [localDataManager.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[localDataManager.stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];
    [localDataManager.stack saveContext];

    // Remove row from table
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work :/ i got an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: This means that your attempt to remove a record from core data is failing. You need to figure out why.

Comment: but when i go back to the app I can see the deletion is made, but from some reason it crushes in the delete the row line

Comment: this is why I shared the LocalDataManager class so maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong there

Comment: Then your `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning the wrong number of rows after deleting a row from core data.

Comment: I think you right, something is weird for me there with the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo object, can you maybe look at this line in the table view and see if you can spot something?..thank

Comment: I've never used core data so I'm no help there. The code in my answer is required but it exposes another issue that I can't help with.